# How to take out some part of a string which contains a mathematical expression and give the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm working on a command for a discord bot:
Someone types `/calc (some-math-expression)`, eg. `/calc 4+5`.
I'd like to evaluate `4+5` and display the answer.
For this, I believe I have to take the `'4+5'` out of the string, calculate it, and return the answer.
How do I do it?

I tried doing this, it may be stupid, I'm new to this. (I'm using `else if` because I have other inputs for the bot)

```
else if (message.content === '/calc' + exp) {
    return Number(exp);
}
```

Apparently, this doesn't assign the `'(some-math-expression)'` to the `exp` var which I've defined before.
The bot shows no output.

Is there a method that splits the string into `/calc` and something else I could assign to a variable automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55332811/7133466) would work, this could be used in a malicious way: the code will run everything in the string, so if somebody writes the right thing they could insert code into the bot, making it vulnerable to attacks. They could, for example, turn it off with `/calc client.destroy()` or read its token with `/calc client.token`: it's good practice not to make the `eval` command publicly accessible.

Instead of that, I would use a more secure method, with the `mathjs` package. 
[image: NPM]

You can parse the expression as said in other answers, then use `math.eval()` to make it resolve the expression. You can find the docs [here](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html).

Here's a quick example:

```
var mathjs = require("mathjs");

let cmdString, mathExpression;

// This will just return the expression
function getExp(command = '') {
    return command.split('/calc')[1].trim();
}

cmdString = "/calc4+5"; // If this is the command...
mathExpression = getExp(cmdString); // ...this will be '4+5'
// Make the result with mathjs.eval()
let result = mathjs.eval(mathExpression); // 9
```

This is an easy way that works even with more complex operations, like `sqrt()` and `cos()`. It will also work with imaginary numbers and all sorts of stuff that no one would ever ask to a Discord bot.

You can try the package with RunKit: [link](https://npm.runkit.com/mathjs).

Comment: Makes sense. Quick questions: what does *command = ' '* do? Shouldnt it be something like *var command*? Also is trimming necessary? Why? Thank you!

Comment: `command = ''` is just setting the default value of the command argument to '' for a more robust code.

Comment: `command =''` is there only because I'm used to do stuff in this way, but you could simply write `command`, since if the string is wrong an error would be thrown anyway. Trimming is not strictly necessary, but I think it's better: mathjs will understand the string even if you don't trim it, but if you need to log the expression or put it in a message then it's better to have it already trimmed

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way for you to parse your input would be to use `String.split`. That is...

```
const words = message.content.split(' ');
const command = words[0];
const variables = words.splice(1).join(' ');
```

here command will become '/calc' and variables will become '4+5'

This works because in any input that you need your discord bot to handle, the first word will always be the command.

Comment: it will return '4 + 5' I think...not sure what OP needs, but another regex could strip all whitespace if needed.

Comment: Ah, Sorry I wasn't clear. I was making a calculator, so preferably 4 + 5 should work too. Thanks, though!

Answer (score -1):

```js
let message = '/calc 4+5'

let equation = message.replace(/\/calc/, '').trim();
let answer = eval(equation)
console.log(equation+' =', answer )
```

You can achieve your function using the following Regular expression.

```js
let message = '/calc 4+5'

if (equation = message.match(/^\/calc(.+)/)) {
 let answer =  eval(equation[1].trim());
 console.log(equation[1]+' =',answer)
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the other way? That made more sense. Thanks!

Comment: sure added it back @ManasvChhabra

Comment: If you don't mind me asking why is thre /\/calc/ why not just /calc? The first code.

Comment: // is used for making it regex expression i.e. /<your expression>/ and \ used as the escape character as you have / in your string. its same as new RegExp('/calc') ,check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thanks man but this code is harder to understand. So I'll accept the other answer, sorry! I'm sure it'd help someone else. I can't upvote it either, I lack reputation.

Comment: eval() is a security risk, there are ways to eval() commands that go into your system ( out of node.js )

Answer (score -2):

I an not sure how you are getting the `message.content` and `exp`. But, as per my understanding you can do something as follows:

```
let cmdString = "/calc4+5";
let mathExpression = cmdString.split("/calc")[1];
let result = eval(mathExpression);
```

`result` is what your resultant values of the expression.

Thanks...

Comment: Oh the message.content is the input from any user in a discord channel. The exp was my failed try at automatically assigning part of a string to a variable directly.

Comment: Isnt this a mayor Secvurity Risk `/calcclient.token`

Comment: Please DO **NOT** DO THIS: by making `eval()` publicly usable you're exposing your bot to all sorts of attacks (including them reading your token, as mentioned by @PLASMAchicken). I've proposed a way that won't compromise your bot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343656/7133466)